# Need to convert a numeric field to date in this query

Tags: sql, db2

I am running this in sql server but there is an error on the date compare as the column cadodt is a numeric. Is there a quick and easy way to convert that col to numeric? It's date is in YYYYMMDD but I cannot compare against a date field like current date.

```
select * from openquery(IBSIBM, 'select CABANO, CABCRC, CABCTR, CABCUR, CABKCO, CACLVL, CACOTI,    
    CACRDT, CACTTP, CADODT, CADOTY, CAEXRT, CAIDNO, CAJONO, CANCRX,   

    CAPERI, CAREFX, CARSCD, CASCRC, CASCTR, CASTAT, CASTMT, CASYID,   
    CATIML, CATREF, CATTXT, CATYPC, CAUSER, CAVADT, CAVODT, CAVONO,   
    CAVOTY ,NANAME  from CA1665AFCV.SROCBA, 
                                   CA1665AFCV.srolta,
                                      CA1665AFCV.sronam                         
     WHERE  CADOTY = ''CHK''    and cajono=ctjono and cadodt = CURRENT DATE()
    and caperi=ctperi and caidno=ctidno and ctveno=nanum     
    and CASTAT = ''Y''')
```

Comment: What is the exact error message? I assume that you're using SQL Server, since you're using OPENQUERY, but you should add that to the tags for the question.

Comment: without knowing precisely where that query is executed we have to guess what the syntax is, date functions are amongst the most specific to certain database vendors. also you state it is YYYYMMDD but is that an integer? or a char? & please UPDATE THE QUESTION don't put important facts into comments

Comment: It's running against a DB2 database (which should also be added as a tag) as that is the IBSIBM

Comment: Please concentrate on the data type of cadodt. Is it an integer or a string. Please change current date to coŕrect type and format, not cadodt ,  but knowing the data type is vital.

Comment: changed tag to db2. while the query is sent from sql server the question relates to DB2 where the query is executed

Answer (score 1):

You have these options

1. convert cadodt from string to date
2. convert cadodt from intger to date
3. convert current date to YYYYMMDD string
4. convert current date to YYYYMMDD integer

1 and 3 assume cadodt is a string

2 and 4 assume cadodt is an intger

**3 and 4 are the more efficient** approaches as you only change one value.

**e.g.**

(3) if cadodt is a string in YYYMMDD format:

```
AND cadodt = VARCHAR_FORMAT(CURRENT DATE, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

(4) if cadodt is an integer representing YYYYMMDD

```
AND cadodt = YEAR(CURRENT DATE) * 10000 + MONTH(CURRENT DATE) * 100 + DAY(CURRENT DATE)
```

Comment: how to convert current date to string?

Comment: This.  Assuming the OP has an index over cadodt, then only 3 or 4 will make use of the index.  1 or 2 will force a full table (index) scan.

Comment: exactly, which is why I stated **3 and 4 are the more efficient**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `cadodt` is actually an integer or numeric field and not a character string, try this:

```
select * from openquery(IBSIBM,
   'select CABANO, CABCRC, CABCTR, CABCUR, CABKCO, CACLVL, CACOTI,
      CACRDT, CACTTP, CADODT, CADOTY, CAEXRT, CAIDNO, CAJONO, CANCRX,
      CAPERI, CAREFX, CARSCD, CASCRC, CASCTR, CASTAT, CASTMT, CASYID,
      CATIML, CATREF, CATTXT, CATYPC, CAUSER, CAVADT, CAVODT, CAVONO,
      CAVOTY, NANAME
    from CA1665AFCV.SROCBA, CA1665AFCV.srolta, CA1665AFCV.sronam
    WHERE CADOTY = ''CHK''
      and cajono = ctjono
      and cadodt = YEAR(CURRENT DATE) * 10000 + MONTH(CURRENT DATE) * 100 + DAY(CURRENT DATE)
      and caperi = ctperi
      and caidno = ctidno
      and ctveno = nanum
      and CASTAT = ''Y''')
```

Aside: I would strongly recommend *against* using comma joins.  The longer ANSI 92 join syntax is much easier to read and maintain.  I'd also strongly recommend using qualified column names.  This schema is not the easiest to follow as it is.  No need to make it even more arcane.

Answer (score 0):

the `CURRENT DATE()` may be causing you some issues use `CURRENT_DATE()`

Try this:

```
select * from openquery(IBSIBM, 'select CABANO, CABCRC, CABCTR, CABCUR, CABKCO, CACLVL, CACOTI,    
    CACRDT, CACTTP, CADODT, CADOTY, CAEXRT, CAIDNO, CAJONO, CANCRX,   

    CAPERI, CAREFX, CARSCD, CASCRC, CASCTR, CASTAT, CASTMT, CASYID,   
    CATIML, CATREF, CATTXT, CATYPC, CAUSER, CAVADT, CAVODT, CAVONO,   
    CAVOTY ,NANAME  from CA1665AFCV.SROCBA, 
                                   CA1665AFCV.srolta,
                                      CA1665AFCV.sronam                         
     WHERE  CADOTY = ''CHK''    and cajono=ctjono and cadodt = CURRENT_DATE()
    and caperi=ctperi and caidno=ctidno and ctveno=nanum     
    and CASTAT = ''Y''')
```

Comment: that's not the issue. the issue is need to convert the col cadodt to a datetime

Answer (score 0):

Replace `CADODT = CURRENT DATE()` with:

```
date(substr(char(CADODT), 1, 4) || '-'|| substr(char(CADODT),5, 2) || '-'|| substr(char(CADODT), 7, 2)) = CURRENT DATE
```

That should convert it from an integer to a date.

Comment: why change every row of data when you could change just the single current date instead?